# How to connect ESP32 to the iPhone Using EAAccessoryManager Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, esp32

I try to connect my ESP32 to My apple phone using  EAAccessoryManager, But i can't:
Conected devices is always null, and don't found any device. Someone can help me please. That's my code i need to connect it: He don't found any device, always connectedAccessoires count is 0

```
    public void Start()
    {
        var connectedAccessories = EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.ConnectedAccessories;
        EAAccessory beeWiCar = null;

        foreach (var accessory in connectedAccessories)
        {
            foreach (var protocolString in accessory.ProtocolStrings)
            {
                protocolString.Contains("com.beewi.controlleur");
                beeWiCar = accessory;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (beeWiCar != null)
        {
            try
            {
                session = new EASession(beeWiCar, "com.beewi.controlleur");
                session.Accessory.Disconnected += delegate
                {
                    new UIAlertView("BeeWi Car", "BeeWi car disconnected", null, "OK").Show();
                };

                session.InputStream.Schedule(NSRunLoop.Current, NSRunLoop.NSDefaultRunLoopMode);
                session.InputStream.Open();
                session.OutputStream.Schedule(NSRunLoop.Current, NSRunLoop.NSDefaultRunLoopMode);
                session.OutputStream.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new UIAlertView("BeeWi Car", "Ups something went wrong.", null, "OK").Show();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            new UIAlertView("BeeWi Car", "No BeeWi car connected", null, "OK").Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the Bluetooth on the ESP32 & iPhone is on? Are you able to connect to the bluetooth directly through the settings (outside the app)?

Comment: Hello @Saamer Thank's for answers, Sorry because I'm not good in english, So I'm sure bluetooth is on in my iphone and ESP32, But iphone can't found ESP#@ beetween available devices in bluetooth settings. I don't know why, but for android phone i found ESP32 without any problems!!! Thank's again

Comment: Did my solution work for you? You can also try the shiny nuget package

Comment: @Saamer I have try shiny, but in my app i need to send a long message for ESP32, and bluetooth ble you can't send more than 185 byte in ios and 512 in android, That's why i need to use bluetooth classique, So the problem now it's when I try the code, Always I don't fond any device to connect, so please if you can give me a simple exemple of code. I have search in a lot of code but without any result... I have always 0 device !! Thank you Bro

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T-Ett-ECKk0jm-RBPeehXeWbw76SsJsp/view?usp=sharing @Saamer It's exemple, always 0 discovereed device

Comment: Can you please share your code on github instead of google drive? Did the code I shared below not work?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing this part of the code needed to actually look for the bluetooth devices and pick from the list:

```
EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.RegisterForLocalNotifications();
TaskCompletionSource<EAAccessory> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<EAAccessory>();
connectionObserver = EAAccessoryManager.Notifications.ObserveDidConnect((s, e) =>
{
    tcs.SetResult(e.Selected);
});

try
{
    await EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.ShowBluetoothAccessoryPickerAsync(null);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.UnregisterForLocalNotifications();
    return null;
}
```

[Here's a good example](https://github.com/inthehand/32feet/blob/eae78b737eb8e80785d330d4bd964505c8e96248/InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth/Platforms/iOS/BluetoothDevicePicker.iOS.cs) of it's implementation on iOS.